# htaccess rewrite to GET value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my URL so it becomes the value of a GET variable. For example, I would like:

`http://www.example.com/forums/f?forum=90`

to become:

`http://www.example.com/forums/f90`

Note: I'd like the `f` to come before the number in the rewritten URL, as I have numbered folders in the same directory that will cause collisions and confusion. Also, I'd like the GET variable to still work, which I assume is done using `QSA`

So far, everything I've tried causes 404 errors. This is my current attempt, which causes EVERY page to become a 404 error:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ f.php?forum=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Edit:**
These are the current rewrite rules I already have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]


# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Does the page show fine as desired without the rewrite in place? And what system are you using (ie forum software) and does it cater for re-written URLs? I'd guess not, and is why you get a 404 (rather than 500 to say badly configured htaccess)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm using a standard Apache shard hosting system uhosted by TSOhost. I built the whole site on PHP (no plugins or software such as Wordpress). It all works fine without the redirect rules, but after I put one in, it either doesn't work, gets 404 errors or redirects to the index page of /forums

Comment: I'm just really looking for a way to rewrite the URL I gave as an example to the second example URL I gave in my question. I've looked all over but to no avail

Comment: So the code you made, is it configured to handle the re-written rules? I presume your data is in the DB? If so (or however it's stored) when your application gets the URL, and knows what to do with `forum=90` to get data for that URL/Page, does your application also know how to get data when it's presented with `f90`?

Comment: The plan is supposed to be that htaccess will make the page `f90` be the same as the page `f.php?forum=90`. I know it's possible, I just don't know **how**

Comment: You now get `/forums/f90` from using anubhava's re-write, so isn't the re-write now working as you require? Your original URL was `forums/f?forum=90`, so the new URL of `/forums/f90` is surely all you need - the f90 IS the GET info. You also stated *"this works still: /forums/f?forum=90"* - how does that work if re-write is in place? You should never get that URL. If  you are happy with the re-write working, maybe it's time for a new question asking why your back end is not handling the new URL structure correctly. Or if not, can you explain a bit more clearly what you need and what happens?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know anymore. All the pages were loading some old, disused code. I'm not even sure what was going on and I'm thinking of giving up this whole rewrite thing completely! :P

Comment: Sounds like you are so close...

Answer (score 1):

Have this rule in `/forums/.htacces`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forums/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^f(.+)$ f.php?forum=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten so far. After putting your code in, `/forums/f90` is now considered a valid page and is showing as I'd expect, but without the GET variable. I thought QSA was supposed to send the GET variable to the PHP script? Or am I mistaken? My PHP script displays results from a MySQL table based on the value of the GET variable. It appears that the GET variable isn't being passed to the script when this rewrite rule is used. How would I go about using this GET variable still? **Edit:**I'm not trying to get it to display the variable still, just pass the value to the script

Comment: For example, this works still: `http://www.chloecrayola.co.uk/forums/f?forum=90`, and this works: `http://www.chloecrayola.co.uk/forums/f90?forum=90`, however, this shows the basic page structure without the MySQL data: `http://www.chloecrayola.co.uk/forums/f90`

Comment: In fact, I've just notice that the only part of the site that's showing is the "reply" section, however it is laid out differently from the one that is on the page that is working. Basically, the reply form looks like the one I use on a `/spam` page in the main root folder... I am so confused it's unreal

Comment: Fourth comment... on further investigation, I found that the page that was showing was in fact the `/spam` page... So, basically, I'm afraid to say that your code didn't work as planned at all. I'm starting to think about giving up and just having messy URLs forever. It'd be much less painful than this!

Comment: I think you need to clarify the pretty URL scheme you want first. You wrote real URLs are: `http://www.chloecrayola.co.uk/forums/f?forum=90` and `http://www.chloecrayola.co.uk/forums/f90?forum=90` Do these URLs work even when you remove `/forum/.htaccess`? How is it `/forum/f` in one case and `/forum/f90` in another case? What is your `.php` file name to handle these URLs? Do you already have some rules in `/forum/.htaccess`?